# Shopify Liquid: Adding Sections to the Login Template

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a client request to add manageable content to the login page. I assume this would work like managing any other page, simply create a section with the necessary schema and markup, then include that section  ({% section 'section_name' %}) in the customers/login.liquid theme template. Problem is I don't see an option to select the login page in the page selection drop-down when customizing the theme. How do I allow my client to customize the login page via sections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual login template cannot have manageable sections.

The closest workaround is to create a custom page template that includes a login form. The page can include manageable sections that are accessible when customizing the theme. The only issue is that all the automatically generated login url links will not go to this page, so any instances of those links need to be adjusted in the theme.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually tell the customizer where to go by adding a hash(`#`) at the end of the url, followed by the shopify site path you want to visit/edit.

```
https://<domain>.myshopify.com/admin/themes/<theme-id>/editor#/account/login
```

Once you enter this in the browser url bar, you'll need to hit enter twice to get the page to reload properly.

If you do this and find it keeps sending you back to the homepage, it means that accounts are disabled on the Shopify store. You can change this by going to:

`Shopify Admin > Settings > Checkout > Customer accounts`

Then selecting either: `Accounts are optional` // `Account are required`

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked, though I appreciate the feedback.